# Get embedded JSON data in div using selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping

I am new to scraping with Selenium and am stumped on how to extract a JSON that is conveniently available directly within a div. The div even contains a tag named `data-json`

The basic code I have so far is:

```
#this works perfectly

from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER_PATH = '/my/path/to/driver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH) 
driver.get('https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=IL1R1')


#this errors out
element = driver.find_element_by_data_type('Biological')

#this also errors out
driver.execute_script('return JSON.stringify(window.dataJSON)
```

The JSON that I am looking for is a div within a div, where the outermost div has a tag `data-type='Biological'` and the innermost div contains the JSON data itself:

[image]

Note that this webpage contains a few other embedded JSONs so the `data-type` in the parent div is important to specify.  Any guidance on how to extract this JSON as a string variable would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER_PATH = '/my/path/to/driver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH) 
driver.get('https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=IL1R1')

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#enhancerControllerComponent > div').get_attribute("data-json")
# goTermController
# element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#go_func > div.gc-subsection-inner-wrap > div > div').get_attribute("data-json")

j = json.loads(str(element))

print(j)
print(type(j))
```

if u want to fetch new element just do the follow step
1.find element in "Developer tools"
2.right click "the element"
3."copy"->"copy selector"
4.change`find_element_by_css_selector`part like what i do

Comment: this runs and returns a JSON, but it is the incorrect one - when I change #enhancerControllerComponent to #goTermController - it doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm thinking you may parsing the wrong way,I update my answer u can try it out